# Android sound ins't playing when button is clicked because of layout bug

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I'm making a soundboard and when the user clicks the buttons a sound byte is supposed to play. I'm pretty sure that my logic in the code is correct to set the sounds to each button as I searched for an off by one error in my for loop. For some reason there is always only one random button on the screen that doesn't play its sound when clicked and the button that doesn't work changes every time I run the code. I think its an error in my XML because every time I change the XML to try to fix it a different button is the one that doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ben.soundboard.MainActivity"


>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button9" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer ohBaby = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.oh_baby);
    MediaPlayer fourTwentySount = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.four_twenty);
    MediaPlayer anotherOne = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.another_one);
    MediaPlayer terrorist_win = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.terrorists_win);
    MediaPlayer allahu_akbar = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.allahu_akbar);
    MediaPlayer cough = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cough);
    MediaPlayer that_was_easy = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.that_was_easy);
    MediaPlayer horn = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.horn);
    MediaPlayer ethan_bradberry = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.im_ethan_bradberry);
    MediaPlayer[] sounds = {ohBaby,fourTwentySount,anotherOne,terrorist_win,allahu_akbar,cough,that_was_easy,horn,ethan_bradberry};

    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    ImageButton button6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    ImageButton button7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    ImageButton button8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    ImageButton button9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    ImageButton[] buttons = {button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9};

    for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++) {
        buttons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        setButtonSound(buttons[i],sounds[i]);
    }

}
public void setButtonSound(ImageButton btn, final MediaPlayer sound)
{
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any error or just nothing happens?

Comment: @codeMagic I don't get an error but the sound doesn't play when I click the button.

Comment: *" every time I change the XML to try to fix it a different button is the one that doesn't work."* is it always a different *sound* also or the same one?

Answer (score 0):

You have not a common implementation, but before start a new sound, stop the reproduction in any MediaPlayer:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++) {
        sounds[i].stop();
 }
```

And then use the method prepare() before start():

```
sound.prepare();
sound.start();
```

I think that your problem is that you are creating several MediaPlayers at the same time but you have to stop playing before start to reproduce a new "sound" with another MediaPlayer.